# How to downgrade from service latest service fabric runtime 5.3.311 to 5.3.301?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

The Web platform installer only installs the latest version.
I have also tried using offline installer, but it seems there is an existing issue with 5.3.301 runtime fresh install on Windows10 anniversary version. Please help. I'm stuck here very bad. Any other possible ways to install?

Comment: Have you tried using [Start-ServiceFabricClusterUpgrade PowerShell cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-windows-server)?

Comment: @cassandrad: I could not find the downgrade framework cmldet here.

Comment: Are you trying to downgrade local debug environment or on-premises cluster?

Comment: did you see this post? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/10/13/release-of-sdk-2-3-301-and-runtime-5-3-301-for-windows/

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade? 5.3.301 has a problem with windows 10 anniversary edition, so that won't work for you if you're running that OS.